# Axios giving bad response with domain:port

Tags: node.js, axios

In my node app, I'm trying to make a `GET` request to another server by Axios:

```
axios.get(`http://my-domain:2095/server/get-status`)
.then(result => { console.log(result.data) });
```

console.log shows me something like this (which is supposed to be JSON):

> \x1F�\b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03tα\x0E� \x14\x05�\x7F�3\x03/
> ��\f��8���\x12�\x04i\x17¿�j��g8\x15{Z%Ep�*��(9�\r<U�\x02\x06\r�x\x07���\��E0�^[OD�j��U�\x7F���r�)���mV�a�\x1D<�M�\x15R\x19���xc�\x04\x00\x00��\x03\x00\x02d&��\x00\x00\x00

**The output is OK when I use `ip:port` in address**. But not with `domain:port`.
Also The response of `http://my-domain:2095/server/get-status` is OK when I enter it in browser and Postman.
So what is the problem with Axios?

Comment: check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74565383/nodejs-axios-response-wrong-encoding/74567820#74567820)

Comment: @BenchVue Thanks. That solved the problem. Can you post it as an answer to be accepted?

Comment: OK, go ahead even if other place also posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In axios v1.2.1, it fixed this error.

You need to add `Accept-Encoding` with `application/json` in axios.get header.

code in v 1.2.0

```
axios.get(`http://my-domain:2095/server/get-status`,
    {
        headers: {
            'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json',
        }
    })
   .then(result => { console.log(result.data) });
```

OR fixed in v1.2.1

```
axios.get(`http://my-domain:2095/server/get-status`)
   .then(result => { console.log(result.data) })
```